# How to detect from within Python whether packages are managed with conda

Tags: python, conda

I would like to detect in a general way from within a Python session whether it is managed by conda.

A few ideas that are not general enough to be useful:

#### 1: Use environment variables

As mentioned in [How do I find the name of the conda environment in which my code is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539623/how-do-i-find-the-name-of-the-conda-environment-in-which-my-code-is-running)

```
import os
is_conda = 'CONDA_PREFIX' in os.system or 'CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV' in os.system
```

This seems not to work in the root conda environment, where these variables are not always defined. It also has potential false positives if conda happens to be activated while you are using another Python installation.

#### 2: Check the executable path

```
import sys
is_conda = ('anaconda' in sys.executable) or ('miniconda' in sys.executable)
```

This will work in the case that users install anaconda/miniconda in the default path. It may fail otherwise. It's also easy to imagine false-positives.

#### 3. Check the version info

As noted in the answers to [any way to tell if user's python environment is anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282363/any-way-to-tell-if-users-python-environment-is-anaconda), you can check the Python version string in some cases:

```
import sys
is_conda = ('Continuum Analytics' in sys.version) or ('Anaconda' in sys.version)
```

This works currently for Python installed from the default channel, but this is quite brittle and may break in the future, particularly with Continuum's company name change. It also probably fails if Python is installed from a third-party source like conda-forge.

#### 4. Check the `conda` import

```
try:
    import conda
except:
    is_conda = False
else:
    is_conda = True
```

This works as long as you're in the root conda environment, but generally fails if you're in another conda env where the `conda` package is not installed by default.

#### 5: Try `conda` to see if it works

Suggestion from Atto Allas [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47608532/how-to-detect-from-within-python-whether-packages-are-managed-with-conda?noredirect=1#comment82175830_47608532):

```
import subprocess
try:
    retcode = subprocess.call(['conda', 'install', '-y', 'pip'])
except:
    is_conda = False
else:
    is_conda = (retcode == 0)
```

This works in the simplest cases, but fails in the common case of using multiple kernels in Jupyter, where the `conda` executable may or may not be connected to the current Python kernel.

---

Is there any *entirely general* way to detect from Python whether that Python installation is managed by conda?

Comment: Is there any specific thing you want to check this for? Maybe solving that would be easier...

Comment: I want to check from within Python whether I should use pip or conda to install a new package.

Comment: You could check whether `path.join(sys.prefix, "bin", "conda")` or `path.join(sys.prefix, "Scripts", "conda.exe")` exists

Comment: This is also needed in, for example, PyInstaller so that it can find DLLs and so on.

Comment: I encountered a problem with this solution. A user installed python and conda in same directory, `/usr/local`, and uses python outside conda. In this case `/usr/local` will be detected as a conda environment.

Comment: @Cruise Which solution? OP only mentioned imperfect ones. Did you mean to comment on one of the answers?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
import sys, os
is_conda = os.path.exists(os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'conda-meta'))
```

Comment: Good approach! Though I think ``conda-meta`` is only in the root environment path though, yes? If you change it to ``conda`` and use ``os.path.join`` for windows compatibility, I think this is probably the best answer.

Comment: I think that an approach like this, where one chacks that `sys.prefix` looks like a conda environment is the best way to go.

Comment: This doesn't work in a virtualenv because conda-meta isn't written to the env.  Using sys.base_prefix instead of sys.prefix works.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best approach is a variation on [Ross Hynten's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47610844/2937831): in the build process, conda [creates a file](https://github.com/conda/constructor/blob/2.0.1/constructor/install.py#L218-L234) called `{sys.prefix}/conda-meta/history`, so checking for its presence should tell you if you're using conda in a reasonably robust manner:

```
import sys, os
is_conda = os.path.exists(os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'conda-meta', 'history'))
```

It remains possible to have false-positives with this approach, but seems to me very unlikely unless done deliberately.

Answer (score 3):

Using compile-time flags seems like it'd be reasonably accurate, and hopefully stable going forward.

```
def is_conda():
    import sysconfig
    return 'conda-bld' in sysconfig.get_config_var("abs_srcdir")
```

I'm not sure about that specific key "abs_srcdir", but `sysconfig.get_config_values()` has many items that may work. With my system python it's:

```
>>> sysconfig.get_config_var("abs_srcdir")
'/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Binaries/python/python-97.50.7~5/TempContent/Objects/2.7/python'
```

And with my conda python it's:

```
In [17]: sysconfig.get_config_var("abs_srcdir")
Out[17]: '/Users/ilan/minonda/conda-bld/python-3.6_1482520641897/work/Python-3.6.0'
```

My hope is that compile-time flags are more robust that run-time checks. Runtime things like "is conda in sys.prefix" can be confused by having a Python.org install in a "conda" subdirectory. But the compile-time flags should be OK.

Comment: This is what I get when creating an environment in `/tmp/test`: 
```sysconfig.get_config_vars('abs_srcdir')
['/tmp/test/../work/Python-3.6.3']```

Comment: Is that a conda-based environment?

Comment: Nice idea! I checked with python installed from conda-forge as well, and ``'conda-bld`` is present there as well. Still a bit worried about failures in corner-cases though...

Comment: @TomAugspurger Yes. That is creates with the latest conda from the defaults channel using `conda create -p /tmp/test python`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError
import sys


def is_conda_managed():
    try:
        out = check_output(['conda', 'env', 'list']).decode('utf-8')
        lines = (line for line in out.splitlines() if line[:1] != '#')
        roots = set(line.split()[-1] for line in lines if line.strip())
    except CalledProcessError:
        roots = set()

    return sys.prefix in roots
```

Comment: Thanks! One potential issue I see with this is if someone has two copies of conda installed on their system, you might end up in a situation where this returns False when it should return True, because it's looking in the wrong set of conda envs.

Comment: The `conda` it picks up is the one that's going to be used when installing (IMO)

Comment: Not necessarily: for example, if you're using Jupyter notebook, then the conda package it picks up is the one in the path when ``jupyter notebook`` is started. If there are multiple anaconda/miniconda installations on the machine, the notebook can easily point to a Python kernel associated with another conda installation, and in that case this solution would fail. I've seen this  sort of thing many times when helping students trouble-shoot installation issues in Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

as i read thru the the ideas and their weaknesses, i am not entirely clear by what you mean by 'managed'.

```
└─╼ which -a python
/Users/me/anaconda/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
┌─[ ~/myPython]
└─╼ /Users/me/anaconda/bin/python
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:05:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> quit()
┌─[ ~/myPython]
└─╼ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()
┌─[ ~/myPython]
└─╼ source activate py36
(py36) ┌─[ ~/myPython]
└─╼ which -a python
/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py36/bin/python
/Users/me/anaconda/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
└─╼ python
Python 3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 13:14:59) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()
(py36) ┌─[ ~/myPython]
└─╼ which -a python
/Users/me/anaconda/envs/py36/bin/python
/Users/me/anaconda/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

are the lines:
    Python 2.7.10 (default
    Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (x86_64)
    Python 3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.

more or less what you're trying to capture?  granted these do not always appear and would be brittle at best.  examining the image using the platform might be a step in a useful direction.

```
In [46]: platform.python_build()
Out[46]: ('default', 'Jul 20 2017 13:14:59')

In [47]: platform.python_compiler()
Out[47]: 'GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)'

In [48]: platform.python_implementation()
Out[48]: 'CPython'
```

the are alternatives to conda, i expect, so the q would seem to be broader than conda.

(this an answer, only because this is my very first SO post, and i only have a single reputaion)